# How musicians are chosen to accompany on stage?

Tags: instruments, band, rock-n-roll

I had a question about music concerts. When solo artists do concerts, in the backstage different unknown musicians are accompanying them. So how are these musicians chosen to accompany?

Comment: What do you mean by "backstage"? Do you mean upstage (on stage but farther from the audience) or off stage (not visible to the audience)?

Answer (score 2):

There are several things that come into play, the skill of the musicians, the courtesy of the individuals involved, the personal attraction of one person to another, how their playing blends, how much they're are willing to work for, whether their appearance is deemed appropriate to the act. The list just goes on and on, and every point has its validity. It's usually referred to as "chemistry".

Answer (score 1):

They are professional musicians who got the job through personal contact, through an agent or by responding to an advertisement.  The same way as for any worker in a skilled, specialised field.  As it's an on-stage job, personal appearance and 'style' as well as musical ability will be a consideration.

On tour, or in concert, they will be playing their instruments.  It's too expensive to tour musicians who are just window-dressing.  But on a TV performance they will very likely be miming to a pre-recorded track, particularly when the gig is a one-song spot on a chat show.  Young, attractive female violin players do well in this particular market! And the 'uniform' for male 'rock' musicians seems to invariably include a hat.

I could tell a story of a band who were booked for a foreign TV appearance, miming to tracks. As their regular pianist was unavailable they took a 'ringer', someone who played piano well enough to LOOK right...    Then the agent called.  'While you're over there, I've got you a couple of live gigs too.'

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question. Assume everyone involved is relatively competent musically *(not really necessary with electronic effects or three others playing that instrument, one could just fake it)*

100 performers/bands could have 100 different reasons for choosing people, and each musician they use might be chosen for a different reason.

---

Here's a list of common factors that come into play when such choices are made:

- Regulars they often play with;
- Ambitious musicians that will pay for camera/stage time;
- 'House band' players that play with and help out with any act that
  plays that venue.
- People that a high profile act wants to promote, for example rising
  stars they may want to boost by giving them a place on stage.
- People who look good/right for the atmosphere the performers want to
  create for their music.
- Financial considerations - some musicians might charge more than
  others for their services.
- Musicians who are 'well connected' (or their agents are), so they get
  a spot on stage.
- A union rotation: Often a venue has an agreement with a musicians'
  union - when they need musicians, the union provides them based on
  whoever's turn it is to get a job in the union's rotation.
- Buddies - good friends - sometimes they'll put a buddy up there, good or
  not so good, just to give him "a charge" - a good feeling.

---

The list goes on....